# Akka :: Using messages with different priorities over event stream in ActorSystem

Tags: actor, akka, publish-subscribe, priority-queue

I need to publish messages of different types to  event stream, and those
messages should have different priorities for example, if 10 messages of type
A have been posted, and one message of type B is posted after all, and
priority of B is higher than the priority of A - message B should be picked up
by next actor even if there are 10 messages of type A in queue.

I have read about prioritized messages [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/scala/dispatchers.html#Mailboxes) and created my simple implementation of that mailbox:

```
  class PrioritizedMailbox(settings: Settings, cfg: Config) extends UnboundedPriorityMailbox(

    PriorityGenerator {
      case ServerPermanentlyDead => println("Priority:0"); 0
      case ServerDead => println("Priority:1"); 1
      case _ => println("Default priority"); 10
    }

  )
```

then I configured it in application.conf

```
akka {

    actor {

        prio-dispatcher {
            type = "Dispatcher"
            mailbox-type = "mailbox.PrioritizedMailbox"
        }

    }

}
```

and wired into my actor:

```
private val myActor = actors.actorOf(
  Props[MyEventHandler[T]].
    withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(HIVE)).
    withDispatcher("akka.actor.prio-dispatcher").
    withCreator(
    new Creator[Actor] {
      def create() = new MyEventHandler(storage)
    }), name = "eventHandler")
```

I'm using ActorSystem.eventStream.publish in order to send messages, and my actor
is subscribed to it (I can see in logs that messages are processed, but in
FIFO order).

However looks like it is not enough, because in logs/console I've never seen the
messages like "Default priority". Am I missing something here? Does the
described approach work with event streams or just with direct invocations of
sending a message on actor? And how do I get prioritized messages with
eventStream?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that your actors are insanely fast so messages get processed before they have time to queue up, so there cannot be any priorization done by the mailbox. The example below proves the point:

```scala
  trait Foo 
  case object X extends Foo 
  case object Y extends Foo 
  case object Z extends Foo 

  class PrioritizedMailbox(settings: ActorSystem.Settings, cfg: Config) 
extends UnboundedPriorityMailbox( 
    PriorityGenerator { 
      case X ⇒ 0 
      case Y ⇒ 1 
      case Z ⇒ 2 
      case _ ⇒ 10 
    }) 

val s = ActorSystem("prio", com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.parseString( 
        """ prio-dispatcher { 
        type = "Dispatcher" 
          mailbox-type = "%s" 
        }""".format(classOf[PrioritizedMailbox].getName))) 
      val latch = new java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch(1) 
      val a = s.actorOf(Props(new akka.actor.Actor { 
        latch.await // Just wait here so that the messages are queued up 
inside the mailbox 
        def receive = { 
          case any ⇒ /*println("Processing: " + any);*/ sender ! any 
        } 
      }).withDispatcher("prio-dispatcher")) 
      implicit val sender = testActor 
      a ! "pig" 
      a ! Y 
      a ! Z 
      a ! Y 
      a ! X 
      a ! Z 
      a ! X 
      a ! "dog" 

      latch.countDown() 

      Seq(X, X, Y, Y, Z, Z, "pig", "dog") foreach { x => expectMsg(x) } 
      s.shutdown()
```

This test passes with flying colors